# ApolloGraphQL & React: Avoid Calling Query & Subscription When Component Re-Mounts?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I have a React router set up like this:

```
       <ApolloProvider client={ApolloClient}>
            <Router history={browserHistory}>
                <React.Suspense fallback={<p></p>}>
                    <ErrorBoundary>
                        <AppStateProvider>
                            <Route render={(routeProps) =>
                                <TopNav
                                    history={routeProps.history}
                                    match={routeProps.match}
                                />
                            }/>
                            <Switch>
                                <Route exact path="/" render={(routeProps) =>
                                    <myComponent history={routeProps.history} match={routeProps.match}
                                    />
                                }/>

                                [.....MORE COMPONENTS.....]

                            </Switch>
                            <Route render={(routeProps) =>
                                <BottomNav history={routeProps.history} match={routeProps.match}
                                />
                            }/>
                        </AppStateProvider>
                    </ErrorBoundary>
                </React.Suspense>
            </Router>
        </ApolloProvider>
```

The `<TopNav>` component contains an Apollo Query and Subscription:

```
function TopNav(props) {

[.......]

let unsubscribeFromIncomingMessages = null; <=== re-runs when user changes routes

[.......]

       <Query query={INCOMING_MESSAGES_QUERY}
               variables={{"localUserId": Meteor.userId()}}>
            {({subscribeToMore, loading, error, data, refetch}) => {
                if (loading) {
                    return (
                        <div key="divLoading"></div>);
                } else {
                }
                if (error) {
                    return (
                        <div key="divError"></div>);
                }

                if (!unsubscribeFromIncomingMessages) {
                    unsubscribeFromIncomingMessages = subscribeToMore({
                        document: INCOMING_MESSAGES_SUBSCRIPTION_QUERY,
                        variables: {
                            "localUserId": Meteor.userId()
                        },
                        updateQuery: (prev, {subscriptionData}) => {
                            [.....HANDLE UPDATE DATA.....]
                        }
                    });
                }

                return (
                    <>
                    </>
                );

            }}
        </Query>
```

When the client brings up another route in my app, `<TopNav>` is re-mounted, which is good, but the `<Query>` and subscription run all over again.

What is the correct way to address this?

**UPDATE**

A breakpoint on my server in the Subscription query, gets hit every single time I navigate to a new page on my client.

Is that **supposed** to happen? If it is, fine! But if not-- I'd like to know that. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>Make variable `unsubscribeFromIncomingMessages` global and</s> add `fetchPolicy='cache-first'` on `<Query>`.

EDIT:
Ooops, I suppose I should have expected that. The subscription will stop as soon as you navigate away from the route, regardless of where you're storing the reference.

`subscribeToMore` is going to run every time you enter the route. Unless you need to be able to stop the subscription, you don't need to record a reference to it. It's not expensive to set up the subscription on entry.

If you need the same subscription active in different routes, you'll need to run it on those routes as well.

My understanding is that the subscription doesn't resubscribe each time, it simply picks up where the last subscription with the same variables, etc., left off.

Comment: That worked! Interestingly, I had a couple of buttons using `<a href=...>`, and they caused the entire site to reload from scratch, including re-declaring the global var. I replaced them with `onClick={() => props.history.push(theHref)}`, and that solved it.

Comment: Update -- I have no idea why at first it appeared to be working ---- but moving it to a global appears to kill the subscription. Hmmm..... I wonder what else might be best practice here?

Comment: Thanks for this info. By any chance can you tell me, is it the same in a `<Subscription> component` -- i.e. does it resubscribe on every refresh -- and unsubscribe itself on every component unmount?

Comment: Yes, it will stop on every component unmount as well.